# Pub/sub on one or multiple channel?

Tags: redis

We have a redis server and I would like to know which solution is the best (in terms of performance or software usage) :

- we publish a message "update" on the channel "product-XX" (where XX is the id of the product) and the subscribers loops through their products and subscribe to the channels
- we publish a message "update-XX" (where XX is the id of the product) on the channel "product" and the subscribers subscribe to the channel "product" and split the message for knowing on which product the update happened.

Comment: Obviously, both have their advantages and disadvantages. Which to choose, depends on your app, your data, your usage of it.

Comment: Can you tell me what I need to tell you in order to get an advice ?

Comment: Actually, why don't you publish both messages? So that clients can listen to only what they need.

Comment: What are the consequences in publishing or subscribing to many channels (possibly thousands) on the server and client side ?

Comment: More channels means more resource usage.

Comment: Can you be more precise ? Everything is more resource usage.

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. What do you mean, "what are the consequences"?

Comment: I'd like to know what is done on server side when you publish to a new channel and on the client and server side when you subscribe to many channels. I mean internally.

Comment: For example, when you publish a message, the server walks all sockets associated with it, and pushes the message into them. http://redis.io/commands/publish. Review documentation on other pubsub commands too. If you still have questions after that, then it's time to look at some source code.